# Table Search - adding 'no results' message

Tags: javascript, search

I am currently using the below table search/filter script in a prototype I am building.  User feedback suggests that I need a message when the search returns no matches.

I was wondering if someone could suggest a change that would show a no results message when a user searches for something not found on the table?

The idea is to display it only once as long as the string is not found.  Once the search field is refreshed or altered the search/filter would begin again.

NOte: I have seen this same question asked but not with the code base I am using, and I am a user of script but do not fully understand the language, so I cannot apply the suggestions to my code.

Thanks

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#search').keyup(function()
            {
                searchTable($(this).val());
            });
        });
        function searchTable(inputVal)
        {
            var table = $('#tblData');
            table.find('tr').each(function(index, row)
            {
                var allCells = $(row).find('td');
                if(allCells.length > 0)
                {
                    var found = false;
                    allCells.each(function(index, td)


                    {
                        var regExp = new RegExp(inputVal, 'i');
                        if(regExp.test($(td).text()))
                        {
                            found = true;
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    if(found == true)$(row).show();else $(row).hide();
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have a row that shows "no Results", and you can decide whether to show it or not when you find results. So you should store a variable, for example `foundResults` and at end, check it an decide whether to show it or not.

Something like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#search').keyup(function()
        {
            searchTable($(this).val());
        });
    });
    function searchTable(inputVal)
    {
        var table = $('#tblData');
        var foundResults = false;
        table.find('tr').each(function(index, row)
        {
            var allCells = $(row).find('td');
            if(allCells.length > 0)
            {
                var found = false;
                allCells.each(function(index, td) {
                    var regExp = new RegExp(inputVal, 'i');
                    if(regExp.test($(td).text()))
                    {
                        found = true;
                        foundResults = true;
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                if(found == true)$(row).show();else $(row).hide();
            }
        });
        if (foundResults) {
            $(".noresults").hide(); 
        } else {
            $(".noresults").show();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: it looks like there is a scripting error.       searchTable($(this).val());
        });
    });  - (so says dreamweaver)

Comment: @Ben do you know anything about js or are you just trying stuff? I can't help you with so little details.

Comment: Yes, I am a user but do not know the language.  I started using js in my prototyping.  I will research a fix to your solution a little more - thanks.

Comment: Looking at the code maybe I am misunderstanding.  My table data is shown by default, when the user searches/filters then the other rows are hidden, except for the row where a match has been found.  Is your 'noresults' row supposed to remain hidden until a search is made where no results are found, and then the row is shown?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea, to have "noresults" row hidden/visible depending on the case